# Empty file with MVC file download

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566135/file-not-found-error-with-filestreamresult-controller-action) on this matter, where the file was not being produced, the file returned by the following code is now empty.  My controller action is declared as follows, then has a body that generates CSV lines from records for export.  The CSV generation works.

```
[Authorize(Order = 0, Roles = "Requester,Controller,Installer")]
public FileStreamResult ExportJobCards()
```

In the following code that should return a populated CSV file, `lines` is of type `List<string>` and has 126 items.  `sw.BaseStream` has the value 770048 for both its *Length* and *Position* properties.  A zero byte file is returned to the browser, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to "rewind" the stream before you return it in the result.  I think something like the following this would work:

sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);