# MVC3 + Streaming images from the Database is causing very high CPU usage on my server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cpu-usage, memorystream, filestreamresult

I have this site that streams images from the database (SQL2008), and I think it's the one causing the very high CPU usage on my server. The CPU usage is at least 60-90%.

I am using MVC3 and below is the code in my Controller that sends the image to the View:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "GUID")]
 public FileStreamResult GetFile(string guid)
    {
        Guid id = new Guid(guid);
        Thumbnail thumbnail = thumbService.GetThumbnailByGUID(id);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(thumbnail.FileContent.ToArray());
        var fsr = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image");
        return fsr;
    }
```

The View:

```
 <div style="background:url('@url');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% top;background-color:#fff;" class="photoThumb">
```

The @url above is /GetFile/guid

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Updates on the answer and another question:

The [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "GUID")] from the answer below worked and has improved the performance of the site. The CPU usage has now went down to 8-60% but I also want to make sure that everything is disposed so I want to know if FileStreamResult is doing that for me or should I do it manually?

Comment: Is it possible to store only image path in database instead of whole image?

Comment: @alok_dida Yes it's possible, but that would mean a complete re-do on my end. And I want the images in the database for migration purposes.

Comment: Ok. I would like to add one more thing, please dispose all the objects else there will be an issue of memory lick. You can use using(resource) clause for it.

Comment: @alok_dida, Isn't that already handled by FileStreamResult? I did some research on that one and they are saying that FileStreamResult handles the Dispose. Not sure though. Anyways, I tried Using(Stream stream = new MemoryStream(thumbnail.FileContent.ToArray())){return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image");} but the images doesn't show. Am I doing it wrong? The OutputCache suggested by Stank below works for me but I also want to make sure everything is disposed.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for View and function?

Comment: Hi @alok_dida I have updated the question with the complete code and with the question regarding FileStreamResult.

Comment: Look my below code and also refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084366/how-do-i-dispose-my-filestream-when-implementing-a-file-download-in-asp-net

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11876/discussion-between-alok-dida-and-duncan-mcintyre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that there is a database hit for each image request, with multiple images per page request - this could lead to high CPU usage.  You should try caching the images.

If you decorate your action with

`[OutputCache( Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "id" )]`

this should cache the result image for one day, meaning fewer db queries, and hopefully less load on your server.

Comment: Yes @StanK you are correct, each image request hits the database. Thanks for the advice, I'll try this out and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: the OutputCache works for me. Thanks, but I also want to make sure that everything in my code is disposed. Question: Does FileStreamResult do that for me? Or do I have to do it myself? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify as below.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "GUID")]
     public FileStreamResult GetFile(string guid)
        {
            Guid id = new Guid(guid);
            Thumbnail thumbnail = thumbService.GetThumbnailByGUID(id);
            var fsr; 
            using(Stream stream = new MemoryStream(thumbnail.FileContent.ToArray()))
            {
                fsr = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image");
            }
            return fsr;
        }
```

As mentioned in above comment, when your page render FileStreamResult will automatically dispose.

Comment: @aloka_dida, the above modifications doesn't work. The images are not rendered in my view.

Comment: The reason is that @alok_dida is using the using(stream... statement. This disposes the stream before it can send it.