# ASP.NET MVC FileStreamResult, fileDownloadName is not used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, filestreamresult

The following returns a PDF which the browser tries to directly display inline. This works correctly. However, if I try to download the file, the download name is not "myPDF.pdf", but instead the ID in the route (myapp/controller/PDFGenerator/ID). Is it possible to set the file download name to be "myPDF.pdf"?

```
public FileStreamResult PDFGenerator(int id)
{
    MemoryStream ms = GeneratePDF(id);

    byte[] file = ms.ToArray();
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    output.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    output.Position = 0;
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
    "inline; filename=myPDF.pdf");

    return File(output, "application/pdf", fileDownloadName="myPDF.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, this is not possible with a PDF displayed inline. You could achieve this if you send the Content-Disposition header with as an attachment:

```
public ActionResult PDFGenerator(int id)
{
    Stream stream = GeneratePDF(id);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "myPDF.pdf");
}
```

Also notice how I removed the unnecessary `MemoryStream` you were using and loading the PDF in memory where you could have directly streamed it to the client which would have been far more efficient.

Comment: Yes, that was the whole point of my answer. If you want the file to be displayed inline you **cannot** specify a filename. If you display the PDF file inline, it is opened with the plugin associated on the client machine to open PDF files. Behavior will vary between the various plugins.

Comment: @Nalan M answer could force it to download, in most cases. So, it shouldn't be said as not possible.

Comment: One question, who takes care of disposing the stream here?

Comment: @Legends the FileStreamResponse will dispose it - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3086291

Answer (score 6):

If you are using FileStreamResult to download the file, try using this in controller

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.pdf");
```

Comment: On of my exporting to PDF actions returns data as **plain text** replacing **iframe** instead of attachment type. I had to add these two lines to force it to popup the save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by making the id a string which represents the file name without the extension.

```
public ActionResult PDFGenerator(string id, int? docid)
{
    Stream stream = GeneratePDF(docid);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream , "application/pdf");
}
```

The url then then end like this

```
  ..PDFGenerator/Document2?docid=15
```