# Return FilePathResult Between Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download

Usually, in ASP.NET, MVC or otherwise, we make the client download a file by having the user click a link/button; I assume this link/button action goes to the correct controller then redirects back to the main page. However, how can I cause the download from some intermediate controller, during a series of redirects?

Basically, when the user clicks a button to create a PDF, the action goes to PdfController to create the PDF, then, since I'm assuming he/she wants to download the PDF anyway (if he/she doesn't, he/she can always click "No"), I want to have the browser download the PDF before the page gets rendered again. If I haven't lost you yet, how do I accomplish this?

Here's a sample of what I have so far. Button that starts the action:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" href="@Url.Action("MakePdf", "Pdf")">Create PDF</a>
```

PdfController's MakePdf() method:

```
    public ActionResult MakePdf()
    {
        string PdfUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE") + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH") + "/Sites/Bems/PDF/UserPdfs/report" + Id + ".pdf";
        // create the PDF at this PdfUrl

        return RedirectToAction("ShowPdf", "Pdf", new { PdfUrl = PdfUrl });
    }
```

PdfController's ShowPdf() method, redirected from the previous MakePdf() method:

```
public ActionResult ShowPdf(string PdfUrl)
    {

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(PdfUrl))
        {
            return File(PdfUrl, "application/pdf"); // Here is where I want to cause the download, but this isn't working
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(PdfUrl))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("A PDF file should be here, but we could not find it.");
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Editor"); // Goes back to the editing page
    }
```

I'm trying to cause the download at the place in the code I specified, but I'm not sure how to cause it. Usually you return it somehow to the view, whereas here I'm calling an object, I think, but I'm really fuzzy on how that all works. Regardless, something I'm doing isn't working. Any ideas on what that is?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862683/asp-net-mvc-filestreamresult-filedownloadname-is-not-used

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a problem I'm having, thankfully. I'll keep it in mind, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the ViewResult `RedirectToAction("Edit", "Editor")` and in the same response a FileResult `File(PdfUrl, "application/pdf")`

To accomplish your task you could follow this scenario:

- click on button create pdf
- call the `RedirectToAction("Edit", "Editor");`
- in this case at the end of the view, add a javascript call to the action method returning the FileResult
- once the page is rendered, the download will start automatically

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going to have to do. I wish I could just do it all in ASP, but oh well.