# Serve the image - Close the image resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The below code is working perfect. It serves the specified image.

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)     
  {
      string fileName = string.Format("{0}.png", id);
      FileStream fileStream = File.Open(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName), FileMode.Open);
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(fileStream) };
      response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
      response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
      return response;
  }
```

Just to release the resource that I acquired to read the image file I have modified the code as follows.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)     
{
   string fileName = string.Format("{0}.png", id);
   using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName), FileMode.Open))
       {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(fileStream) };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
            return response;
        }
}
```

I am getting the error "Error while copying content to a stream". Yes. I am closing the resource before it is streamed.

But the question is how to serve the image and still close the unhandled resource?
Asp.Net Web API 2 and above.
Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Look into using `StreamContent` and adding a `MediaTypeHeaderValue` to the response headers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about releasing `FileStream` object. It will closed by lower layers of Web API once response is complete. Code mentioned in your first snippet is fine.

Comment: Do you any documentation to substantiate your statement? I can't convince my colleagues based on this justification.

Comment: @GaneshaK I did not have any particular MSDN url for this topic. But I have answered you based on my experience of serving number of file objects through Web API. You can also refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084366/how-do-i-dispose-my-filestream-when-implementing-a-file-download-in-asp-net/3086291#3086291) for further details