# How to create Excel file using OpenXML without creating a local file?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is it possible to create and edit an excel document using OpenXML SDK without creating a local file?

As per the documentation the `Create` method demands for a `filepath`, which creates a local copy of the file.

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

I'm referring the MSDN article here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153.aspx

My requirement is to create the file, and it should be downloaded by the browser on clicking a button.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use the overload of [`SpreadsheetDocument.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478552.aspx) that takes a `Stream` and pass it a `MemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

//add the excel contents...

//reset the position to the start of the stream
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Note that as per [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084366/how-do-i-dispose-my-filestream-when-implementing-a-file-download-in-asp-net) you don't need to dispose the Stream as it will be done for you by the `FileStreamResult` class.

Comment: This will still buffer the data into memory. I found this option to create an excel file using a write-only non-seekable stream: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/347759/generate-excel-file-on-the-fly-without-using-micro

Comment: I am following the same approach but getting one corrupted file downloaded. could you please help me with this. What can be the reason?

Comment: It can be any number of things to be honest @Amrendra. If you open a new question I'll try to take a look.

Comment: `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` helped me...without this line file was corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer as I spent way too much time searching for this: Another way to save a SpreadsheetDocument to a stream is by calling [SpreadsheetDocument.Clone(Stream s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.clone)

It has the benefit of letting you save to a stream even if you created the document from a file or a stream you don't want to save to.

Comment: Yes, the Clone method is very useful in scenarios with "template" files.