# How to create Excel file in-memory using asp.net and OpenXML on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, openxml

I want to dynamically build an Excel file using asp.net (with OpenXML), on Azure. Ideally (I think) I'd prefer to not generate persistent files that I then have to clean up, I'd rather build the file in-memory and send it back.

I'm just feeling a little out of touch as to the best way to do this; would the best way be to create the spreadsheet - using the

`SpreadsheetDocument Create(Stream stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType type);`

or

`SpreadsheetDocument Create(System.IO.Packaging.Package package, SpreadsheetDocumentType type);` ?

I should be able to use the first overload shown above to serve the file out through the HTTP response stream ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779139/writing-memorystream-to-response-object)), right?

I'm not familiar with the System.IO.Packaging namespace (and WindowsBase.dll from which it comes) - but since it's "IO" I assume some kind of persistent file creation might be involved?

Comment: Does my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887503/how-to-create-excel-file-using-openxml-without-creating-a-local-file/29950024#29950024) help you at all?

Comment: Yes @petelids that does look helpful, let me explore.